# How to find the number of ways the given abbreviations can be formed from the given sentence - java

Tags: java

I'm developing a word building game. I got stuck with the following scenario.

I have a word which is an abbreviation; Also, I have one sentence, from which I have to determine the number of ways it can be formed.

for example:

## 1 abbreviation: ACM

Sentence: academy concern manager.
output: 4.

## 2: abbreviation: RADAR

Sentence: Radio addition ranger.
output: 6

## Ground Rules: atleast one char from each word should be used from each word to form the abbreviation

Explanation:  in second example, from the word radio, rad-ra-r can be used to form the abbreviation in such a way with the following words the entire abbreviation can be achieved. and the order should be maintained.

so far i tried to do something like this

```
public static void checkOccurence(String[] in) {
    String word = "";
    int k = 0, n;
    int total = 0, c = 0;
    int extra = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < in.length; i++) {
        int v = 0;
        n = k;
        word = in[i].toUpperCase();
        if (k < ab.length()) {
            for (int j = 0; j < word.length(); j++) {
                if (k < ab.length()) {
                    if (word.charAt(j) == ab.charAt(k)) {
                        k++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < word.length(); j++) {
            for (int l = 0; l < ab.length(); l++) {
                if (word.charAt(j) == ab.charAt(l)) {
                    if (j != l && l < k - 1) {
                        v += calculateExtra(word, j, l, k);
                    } else if (j == l && l < k - 1 && calculateExtra(word, j, l, k) != 1) {
                        c++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        v += c;
        System.out.println(v);
        if (k == n && v > 0) {
            v = 0;
        }
        total += v;

    }
    if (k == ab.length() && total != 0)
        count += total;
    if (k == ab.length() && total == 0)
        count++;
}
```

Comment: How do you determine how many (from 1 to n) characters of a word would be used?

Comment: "at least one" is very unclear. What rule specifies whether only one, two or more characters? Is it based on the randomness or the common characteristics of the words? If "at least one", then the more results will appear.

Comment: Then describe it in the question in detail and provide another examples.

Comment: What represents the numeral output? (`ACM` -> `4` and `RADAR` -> `6`)?

Comment: What's wrong with your current code? (Be specific please)

Comment: 1.RADio Addition Ranger,
 2.RAdio aDdition rAngeR,
 3.RAdio adDition rAngeR,
 4.Radio ADdition rAngeR,
 5.Radio AdDition rAngeR, which is the 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think it's perfect, and I sure there is a lot to improve, but here is a solution that works on both your example(There may be additional edge cases)
I wrote this as an example of how to approach this problem.
first, we calculate all options and then we check which nodes fulfill all the conditions.
do notice the LowerCase game, it is important!

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
        Node exampleNode = new Node();
        exampleNode.mySentence="academy concern manager".toLowerCase();
        exampleNode.chars="ACM".toLowerCase().toCharArray();
        exampleNode.nextNode();
        System.out.println(getOutput(exampleNode));

        exampleNode = new Node();
        exampleNode.mySentence="Radio addition ranger".toLowerCase();
        exampleNode.chars="RADAR".toLowerCase().toCharArray();
        exampleNode.nextNode();
        System.out.println(getOutput(exampleNode));
    }
    public static int getOutput(Node node){
        int output=0;

        if(node.chars.length==0&& node.mySentence.indexOf(" ")==-1){
            Node nextNode=node;
            String s="";
            while (nextNode!=null){
                 String sub =nextNode.myChar+nextNode.mySentence;
                 s=replaceLast(s.toLowerCase(),"",sub)+s;
                 nextNode = nextNode.father;
            }

            boolean wordWithoutChar = false;
            for (String word:s.split(" ")) {
                boolean noCharInThisWord=true;
                for (char c:word.toCharArray()) {
                    if(c<='Z'&&c>='A'){
                        noCharInThisWord = false;
                    }
                }
                if(noCharInThisWord){
                    wordWithoutChar=noCharInThisWord;
                }
            }
            if(!wordWithoutChar){
                System.out.println(s);
                output++;
            }
        }
        for (Node n:node.nodes) {
            output +=getOutput(n);
        }
        return output;
    }
    public static String replaceLast(String find, String replace, String string) {
        int lastIndex = string.lastIndexOf(find);

        if (lastIndex == -1) {
            return string;
        }

        String beginString = string.substring(0, lastIndex);
        String endString = string.substring(lastIndex + find.length());

        return beginString + replace + endString;
    }

    public static class Node{
        List<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
        Node father =null;
        char myChar=0;
        char[] chars=null;
        String mySentence="";
        public void nextNode() {
            int index=0;
            if(chars.length>0){
                while (index<mySentence.length()){
                    if(mySentence.toCharArray()[index]==chars[0]){
                        Node son = new Node();
                        son.chars = Arrays.copyOfRange(chars, 1, chars.length);
                        son.mySentence=mySentence.substring(index+1);
                        son.father=this;
                        son.myChar= (char) (chars[0]-32);
                        son.nextNode();
                        nodes.add(son);
                    }
                    index++;
                }
            }
            return;

        }
    }

}
```

output:

```
 Academy Concern Manager
 Academy conCern Manager
 acAdemy Concern Manager
 acAdemy conCern Manager
 4
 RADio Addition Ranger
 RADio Addition rangeR
 RAdio aDdition rAngeR
 RAdio adDition rAngeR
 Radio ADdition rAngeR
 Radio AdDition rAngeR
 6
```